# Help me understand this syntax in railstutorial.org (the section on Factory Girl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, railstutorial.org

I am in [chapter 7 of the railstutorial.org,](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec%3atests_with_factories) and the author is starting to explain less and less of the syntax and details of the course.

I dont understand the following syntax he uses when creating a user with Factory Girl:

```
 Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                  "Michael Hartl"
  user.email                 "mhartl@example.com"
  user.password              "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation "foobar"
end
```

I am not copying and pasting the code, so initially, after reading, I wrote my code like this:

```
user.name = 'Michael Hartl'
etc
```

and the tests didnt run. After rereading that section, I saw that the author doesnt use the =. What does this mean? If I understood correctly, Factory girl creates a instance of User, and then assigns it these attributes. So how is user.name = 'whatever' incorrect?

I really hate not understanding stuff when doing tutorials, so I'm stuck here until I make sense of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `user.name = 'Michael Hartl'` doesn't work, because [the creator](http://thoughtbot.com/) of Factory Girl chose a different syntax, namely: `user.name "Michael Hartl"`. I guess you just have accept that [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) works like this. If you want to know *why* you have to ask the [creator](http://thoughtbot.com/).

Comment: @Zach, what do you mean? I don't understand your comment. What I am trying to say is that the creator chose the following syntax: `user.name "Michael Hartl"`. And not: `user.name = "Michael Hartl"`. Where do I say something is *wrong*???

Comment: Can someone please explain what's wrong with this answer?? I don't care about the rep, I want to know what's wrong with it.

Comment: The author of the book wrote the syntax correctly. The poster did not. http://robots.thoughtbot.com/tagged/factory_girl

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying!

Answer (score 2):

This is ruby block syntax and you'll find it everywhere in rails. Look at your migrations for example. What's confusing you is the syntax of assignment and the fact that brackets/braces are (generally) optional in ruby. This allows more readable code which might otherwise be:

```
 Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name("Michael Hartl")
  user.email("mhartl@example.com")
  user.password("foobar")
  user.password_confirmation("foobar")
end
```

[Further reading](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807023/waiting-for-a-factory-girl)

Comment: I am familiar with blocks, thanks. As you said I am just confused by the assignment part. I thought about that, but then, shouldnt the standard assignment syntax (user.name = 'something') work? It doesnt...